# Need to check a windows service, if that service not available execute the msi file via cmd

Tags: command-line, command, command-line-interface, command-prompt

The script need to verify one windows service if that particular service is not available it needs to execute the MSI file (silent installation)

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? And what does "not available" mean? Not registered at all, not yet started, or running but not responding?

Comment: Not available means - Not registered at all. 

Basically, I want to automate one of the software installation. If that service is available that software is already installed on that system. If that's not available I need to execute the msi file to install that software

Comment: This is why i looking a script to automate that installaion task